# What are the gameplay differences between the factions?

Tags: planetside-2

I'd like to avoid remaking my character since it would result in  me [losing anything I unlock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86977/is-it-possible-to-switch-factions-in-planetside-2-after-choosing-one), so before I decide on a faction I'd like to know what the gameplay differences between each of them are.

What are the gameplay differences between the factions?

Answer (score 3):

While searching for this anwser I found a nice little chart with the differences in weapons.

The difference is:

```
TR: High rate of fire with less damage.
VS: Lasers and mobility
NC: High damage low attack speed.
```

[image: Faction differences planetside 2]

Comment: This is a good overview of the weapons, but you should probably mention the differences in the MBTs and ESFs.

Comment: i feel like there are more differences then just weapons

Comment: @Paralytic Well yes, vehicles but they are also weapons tho